# PasteSpecial functionality

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a VBA were in Sheet1, column "A" with different text to copy it to sheet2 "X" amount of times. I want to keep the same text together so I can insert other instructions.

So far I have the following and it's only copying the first line "X" amount of times. Please help. Thanks!

```
Sub TEST()

Dim copytime As Long

Set R = Application.InputBox("Select the range", Type:=8)

Col = R.Columns.Count

copytime = InputBox("How many times to copy")

For i = 1 To copytime

Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, Col).Value = Application.Transpose(R)

Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This code has the capability to handle multi-row source data as well as single rows.

```
Sub TEST()

    Dim CopyTimes   As Long         ' number of duplicates to create
    Dim Rng         As Range        ' selected range
    Dim Col         As Long         ' width of 'Rng'
    Dim Rcount      As Long         ' number of rows in selection
    Dim i           As Long         ' loop counter
    Dim R           As Long         ' target row

    Set Rng = Application.InputBox("Select the range", Type:=8)
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        Col = Rng.Columns.Count
        CopyTimes = InputBox("How many times to copy")
        If CopyTimes > 0 Then
            Rcount = Rng.Rows.Count
            For i = 0 To CopyTimes - 1
                R = (i * Rcount) + 1
                Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(R, 1).Resize(Rcount, Col).Value = Rng.Value
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The amount of time you save with not declaring variables properly is a small fraction of the time you spend dealing with the mistakes and errors resulting from not having a good infrastructure.

I remember a teacher from school who taught us that estimating the volume of globes better be left to those experienced in making such estimates - because they won't even try. Transposed to our subject, the more experienced a programmer the less likely he is to "save time" on his variable declarations.